# Set css property of an element after ng-repeat is finished (with working demo)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page, where on the right side I have a table (file list), 
on the left side I have a filetree (above), and preview image (below).

The point is, the preview image should always stick to the bottom.

Here is an ascii art:

```
+----------+---------------+
| some div |   the         |
+----------+   table       |
|    .     |   on          |
|    .     |   right       |
|    .     |   side,       |
+----------+   filled      |
| DIV stick|   with        |
| to the   |   ng-repeat   |
| bottom   |               |
+----------+---------------+
```

The problem is the **size of table** on the right side 
is **unknown** until ng-repeat is not finished filling with data.
(the size is simply the height of the table header).

I specify the image position on the left with `min-height` css rule.

The goal is to measure the table's height **after** it is fully initialized, and give it to the image as `min-height` css rule (file-preview class).

How I solved it:

**I)** I created a `.directive` when the last element of ng-repeat is executed:
Which fires 'onLastRepeat' signal.

```
.directive('onLastRepeat', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$last) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          scope.$emit('onRepeatLast', element, attrs);
        }, 1);
      }
    };
  });
```

HTML:

```
<tr on-last-repeat="" ng-repeat="file in filelist track by $index">
```

**I/b)** I listen to this event in the controller:

```
$scope.$on('onRepeatLast', function(scope, element, attrs){
  $scope.fmsideheight = $scope.getfmheight;
});
```

**II)** I created a getHeight directive, where it watches the height of the element and set a `getfmheight` variable in the controller.

```
.directive('getHeight', function () {
return {
  scope: {getfmheight: '='},
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, element) {
    scope.getfmheight = element.offsetHeight;
    scope.$watch(element[0].offsetHeight, function (){
      scope.getfmheight = element[0].offsetHeight;
    });
  }
};
});
```

HTML:

```
<div getfmheight="getfmheight" get-height="" id="fm-main" class="col-lg-9 fm-main">
```

**III)** I set the target element height with a yet another directive:

```
.directive('setHeight', function () {
return {
  scope: {fmsideheight: '='},
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function (scope, element) {
    scope.$watch('fmsideheight',function(newValue,OldValue,scope){
      if (newValue){
        element.css('min-height', (scope.fmsideheight+1)+'px');
      }
     });
    element.css('min-height', scope.fmsideheight+'px');
  }
};
});
```

HTML:

```
<div fmsideheight="fmsideheight" set-height="" class="col-lg-3 fm-side" style="overflow-x: auto;">
```

I do believe it is way overkilled solution, and also overcomplicated.

A much simpler solution would be, when the ng-repeat last element is fired I could somehow query a DOM element by #id, and set an another DOM element height by #id. Without $watch-ing everything.

But I read everywhere, accessing DOM element from controllers is a no-go in angular, and I can not make it work that way.

I'm on this isse since a few days already, so any alternative/better solution is appreciated.

Oh and here is a working (with my overcomplicated solution) demo:

http://embed.plnkr.co/OnatXIYLlaIEdcR1zUXJ/preview

(edit window: http://plnkr.co/edit/OnatXIYLlaIEdcR1zUXJ )

When you launch the plunker demo, 
please launch it in a new preview window, 
because it **needs horizontal space**.

Also wait at least 10 sec before hovering on the paw icons. 
Dunno why this delay bug is present.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ng-scope{
position: relative;
}

.fm-side{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;  
width: 25%;
/* remember to switch off your min-height set by js */
}

div#fm-main{
float:right;
}
```

I based on classes which are in code, this can be improved of course.

Worked on your page, made asap, but be remember to check all resolutions as media queries are used in your code.

Comment: thank you for the comment. Sadly position:absolute is out of question, because exactly as you noted because of different screen size we are targeting (phone, tablet, small desktop, large desktop).  Also I would really like to see an angular solution.

Comment: you could add extra class for ng-scope, than maybe it would solve problem, the rest of .ng-scope would be untouched

Comment: Still no, because you can not determine beforehand the height of the table. (imagine a row which breaks to multiple line). My solution works, but I think both setHeight and getHeight directive is unnecessary. There MUST BE a more elegant version. (getElementById directly in controller:)